# How to develop an own browser for Android? How to parse HTML, JS & Co.?

Tags: android, parsing, browser, mobile, w3c

Like the title says, I am thinking about developing my own browser for Android devices.

**My first thought is to know what kind of possibilities I have, before I begin creating my software architecture. Are there any (open?) Browser Engines you could include into your library and reuse them?**
*(There are some unknown browsers in the Android Market and I can't imagine they implemented the parsing).*

Furthermore: If there IS something like I've described before, is it possible to modify (or "fine tune") the render methods? This is one of the most interesting points I guess.

And to end this question and catch the else-case: What would be the alternative way to begin?
[I guess this is not only interesting to know for mobile developers, also for desktop software developers]

**Abbreviated version of this question: I want to develop my own Android Browser. How to begin?**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WebKit Open Source Project](http://webkit.org/).  The Android SDK has a [WebKit package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html) which provides tools and utilities for browsing the web.

Here is an (old) article discussing Android's mobile implementation of WebKit: [Android Uses WebKit](http://webkit.org/blog/142/android-uses-webkit/)

Comment: This is a great approach, thank you for these links.
Do you know something about my concern modify the rendering engine? I guess it's possible in theory, but is it practical? In other words: too much work? or does there exist an interface (or api) for this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest starting point for your own browser would be to check out the standard Android browser's code.
It's all open source, so you can check it out here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser